# Where can I put user input to Func, and avoid sql injection?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to calculate levenstein distance using a custom django function. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.Func

```
lev_dist=Func(F('name'), function='levenshtein', template=f"%(function)s(%(expressions)s, '{symptom.name}')")
```

The problem is that when there is a quote in symptom.name I get an error. The documentation says that you should not put user input into template= because it causes sql injections. If so, where should I put the user input?